# Split the character vector into two parts

Tags: regex, r, split

Consider the following character vector of the length 1:

```
l <- "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/4983410_-iphone-se-64gb-spacegrau-apple.html"
```

I desire to split it into two parts, so that the first part should be:

```
p1 <- "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/4983410"
```

and the second one:

```
p2 <- "_-iphone-se-64gb-spacegrau-apple.html"
```

Surely, one must use regexp to solve the problem. Please could you give me some insight where I can learn manipulation with regular expressions easily. For any help I will be sincerely thankful.

Comment: http://regexone.com is where you can learn the basics. Test the perl=TRUE patterns  at http://regex101.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"(?<=[^_])(?=_)"` with `strsplit` gives you what you need:

```
strsplit(l, "(?<=[^_])(?=_)", perl = T)

# [[1]]
# [1] "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/4983410"
# [2] "_-iphone-se-64gb-spacegrau-apple.html"
```

Comment: What if another underscore appears somewhere before that `_` OP wants to split at?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That means more constraints on the splitting position has to be specified. But it is also possible that the data contains only one underscore which might be known beforehand. I agree OP is not very clear about the point.

Comment: Well, I can add that in that case you can use `(?=_[^_]*$)` lookahead, but the original question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were interested in handling this without regular expressions, you could always use functions like str_split from the stringr package to separate this string.

```
library(stringr)
l <- "http://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/4983410_-iphone-se-64gb-spacegrau-apple.html"
split = stringr::str_split_fixed(l,pattern = "_",2)
p1 = split[1]
p2 = split[2]
```

Comment: This does not yield expected results. Also, what if another underscore appears somewhere before?